# Alternative To Dynamic Query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Need help guys.

I have a stored procedure which displays all of the records.

```
    SELECT 
     Entity.Name as [ENTITY],   
     Product.Name AS [Product Name],   
     convert(date, whseintg.TrnDate) as TrnDate,
     DOGR.AppNo,     
     DOGR.TrnNo,   
     DOGR.TrnType,   
     DOGR.StkId,   
     DOGR_D.ProdId,   
     DOGR_D.Qty,   
     DOGR_D.QtyIn,   
     DOGR_D.UPrice,   
     Ratio.Ratio  
FROM Entity WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     Product WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     DOGR WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     DOGR_D WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     Ratio WITH ( NOLOCK ),
     whseintg WITH (Nolock)  
WHERE ( DOGR_D.ProdId = Product.ProdId ) and  
     ( DOGR.TrnType = DOGR_D.TrnType ) and  
     ( DOGR.AppNo = DOGR_D.AppNo ) and   
     ( DOGR_D.RatioId = Ratio.Ratioid ) and
        ( DOGR.TrnType = whseintg.TrnType ) and  
     ( DOGR.Appno = whseintg.TrnNo ) and        
        ( DOGR.TrnNo is not null ) and      
     ( ( dbo.DOGR.TrnType = 'SCR' ) )  and
     ( dbo.DOGR.LocID = dbo.Entity.LocID)
```

Now, I have certain parameters like `@FromProductName` and `@ToProductName` in the design view of the report.

I don't want to use dynamic queries because it will have a performance impact on the application. What I want is that if there is a value passed in both variables, the query would be something like this:

```
    SELECT 
     Entity.Name as [ENTITY],   
     Product.Name AS [Product Name],   
     convert(date, whseintg.TrnDate) as TrnDate,
     DOGR.AppNo,     
     DOGR.TrnNo,   
     DOGR.TrnType,   
     DOGR.StkId,   
     DOGR_D.ProdId,   
     DOGR_D.Qty,   
     DOGR_D.QtyIn,   
     DOGR_D.UPrice,   
     Ratio.Ratio  
FROM Entity WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     Product WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     DOGR WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     DOGR_D WITH ( NOLOCK ),   
     Ratio WITH ( NOLOCK ),
     whseintg WITH (Nolock)  
WHERE ( DOGR_D.ProdId = Product.ProdId ) and  
     ( DOGR.TrnType = DOGR_D.TrnType ) and  
     ( DOGR.AppNo = DOGR_D.AppNo ) and   
     ( DOGR_D.RatioId = Ratio.Ratioid ) and
        ( DOGR.TrnType = whseintg.TrnType ) and  
     ( DOGR.Appno = whseintg.TrnNo ) and        
        ( DOGR.TrnNo is not null ) and      
     ( ( dbo.DOGR.TrnType = 'SCR' ) )  and
     ( dbo.DOGR.LocID = dbo.Entity.LocID) 
     and (DOGR_D.ProdId between @FromProdID and @ToProdID)
```

Else, it will behave like the original query. Is that possible?

Comment: And please stop using implicit syntax. This is avery poor prgramming technique that will easily lead to incorrect results or accidental cross joins because the joins fileds are spearated from the joins. FUrther, if you need to change to a left join you need to rewrite the whole qwuery becasue you should never mix explicit and implicit joins or you are very likely to get the wrong answer. IN complex reporting queries it is an especially poor practice as you are likely to have many joins. This syntax was replaced 20 years ago, why are you even considering using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try rewriting your final condition:

```
 and (DOGR_D.ProdId between @FromProdID and @ToProdID)
```

as

```
 and DOGR_D.ProdId >= coalesce(@FromProdID, DOGR_D.ProdId) 
 and DOGR_D.ProdId <= coalesce(@ToProdID, DOGR_D.ProdId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the case statement in the where clause. If both the parameters are not null.

AND(
    CASE
     When @FromProductID IS NOT NULL AND @ToProductID IS NOT NULL 
        THEN DOGR_D.ProdId
     END Between @FromProductID AND @ToProductID
  )

use the Above condition instead of

and (DOGR_D.ProdId between @FromProdID and @ToProdID)